# Tables with all columns minimum width except one stretching in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking for a way to get bootstrap to make a table like below:

```
----------------------------------------------------------|
| name |  date  | message                                 |
----------------------------------------------------------|
| test | 12-12  | this one fills up the rest of the space |
----------------------------------------------------------|
| test | 13-12  | this one fills up the rest of the space |
----------------------------------------------------------|
```

All columns should use their minimum width possible while one column stretches over the remaining space. I tried to achieve this with `col-xs-*` but that's far from a dynamic solution.

Any suggestions? Could be custom code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you possibly use `width` with a combination of `max-width`?

If you set the `<th>` to a class or ID (like name is `<th id="name">`, date is `<th id="date">`, etc.), you could accomplish having the rest of the space devoted to the message within the table. Then within your CSS, do something like below:

```
#name {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
#date {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/amrgyvky/)